# DocuSign Objective C Framework libxml2 error

Tags: iphone, objective-c, libxml2, docusignapi

I'm trying to use the DocuSign Framework for objective C projects (https://github.com/jazzdev/DocuSign-iOS-Sample-App) with my project in XCode 5.

In the DocuSign project instruccions says the following:

1. In the Linking section add -lxml2 to Other Linker Flags property
2. In the LLVM GCC Language section add -I/usr/include/libxml2 to the Other C Flags property

I try to follow this instruccions but I obtain an error when I run the project: **"Lexical or Preprocessor Issue 'libxml2/tree.h' file not found"**

I tryed a lot of things and following a lot of stackoverflow questions but my problem is still the same. For example:

[iPhone libxml2 not found during build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6173766/iphone-libxml2-not-found-during-build)

[#import <libxml/tree.h> file not found after xcode update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14622684/import-libxml-tree-h-file-not-found-after-xcode-update)

[Why am I getting this "libxml/tree.h file not found" error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9666804/why-am-i-getting-this-libxml-tree-h-file-not-found-error)

Comment: If the error really says *'libxml2/tree.h' file not found* then there's a wrong include statement somewhere. It should be `libxml/tree.h` (without the `2`).

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but I tried to use the DocuSign example that is more easy. This is the [link](http://iodocs.docusign.com/APIWalkthrough/getEnvelopeDocuments)