# Swift Framework with libxml

Tags: ios, frameworks, swift, libxml2, kissxml

I have Swift Framework project that uses the KissXML Objective-C library. KissXML internally uses libxml.

When I build the xcode project (Xcode 6 - beta 5), I get this error:

`error: <unknown>:0: error: '/SwiftFramework/SwiftFramework/KissXML/DDXMLNode.h:2: include of non-modular header inside framework module SwiftFramework.DDXMLNode`

I have seen this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24103169/swift-compiler-error-non-modular-header-inside-framework-module) that discusses making the relevant header files public. I have done that but I am not sure how to address the case of this header that is imported in the DDXMLNode.h and that is not explicitly part of my project:

`#import <libxml/tree.h>`

Any suggestions on how to handle this?

**Note:** I have used KissXML on a Objective-C only project and it worked fine (Xcode 5).

Comment: Did you manage to solve your problem ?

Comment: Yes. Using a **module** as described below. I marked the answer as the correct answer now.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The trick is to create a **module** and include it on your project.

To create the module you create a file named, let's say, **module.modulemap** which exports the API on the header files of interest like this:

```
module libxmlModuleDevice {
    header "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/usr/include/libxml2/libxml/tree.h"
    export *
}

module libxmlModuleSimulator {
    header "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/usr/include/libxml2/libxml/tree.h"
    export *
}
```

Notice that you need to do this both for the simulator and for the actual device - hence the 2 entries on the file.

This file **module.modulemap** can be placed anywhere. I created a directory called **modules** at the same level as the Xcode's project file (.xcodeproj) and placed the **module.modulemap** file there.

Then add directory that contains this file to the **Header Search Path** under **Build Settings** of you Xcode project.

In this example all you have to do is to add the word **modules** to the **Header Search Path** because the **modules** directory is at the same level as the Xcode project file. This will update internally the Xcode project variable **HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS**. That's it.

Comment: I tried your solution but I can manage to make it work, could you detail more the process ?

Comment: I added more details try it out and let me know how it goes. Cheers.

Comment: Thanks @infinite-loop, I did what you said, and Xcode is able to find the new module, however, at the compile phase, it will throw an error "libXmlModuleDevice" (or whatever) not found :/

Comment: Hhhhmmmm... Can you 2x check that the 2 paths exist on your the file system? If not please adjust them them to point to the correct paths.

Comment: I did it (I upvoted the answer), my project contains two target, I have to add it to both build settings. Thanks :]

Answer (score 2):

in xcode6, iphone8.3, the path will be

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.3.sdk/usr/include/libxml2

*update:
a more easy way:
$(SDKROOT)/usr/include/libxml2

thank to:
[iPhone libxml2 not found during build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6173766/iphone-libxml2-not-found-during-build)